# Javascript code for newbies

Tags: javascript

Im a newbie in javascript and i want you to help me to transform this code from  ***for***  to  ***while***

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('_3hqu'); 
for(var i=0; i<el.length;i++) { 
el[i].click(); 
}
```

When i run this code in chrome console it works.
But when i try my own ***while*** code its not working, can you help me find my errors?

```
    while (true)
{
    if ( el[0].length != 1 )
    {
        if ( el[1].length = 0 )
        {
            el[1].click();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    else if ( el[0].length = 0 )
    {
        el[0].click();
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('_3hqu'); 
}
```

Also if i want to check all the "el" and when it finds the last one to scroll down???

check this out

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('_3hqu'); 
    var objDiv = document.querySelector("._1v31 .uiScrollableAreaWrap");
    var n = -1;
    while (true)
    {
        if (n == el.length) 
        {
            break;
        }   
        else
        {
            objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
        }
         n = el.length;
         var el = document.getElementsByClassName('_3hqu'); 
    }
```

Something like this one, but this is not working.
i get the error

*`TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null`*

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `for` loop can be transformed to a `while` loop like this:

```
for (a; b; c) {
  d;
}
```

to:

```
a;
while (b) {
  d;
  c;
}
```

So your `for` loop as a `while` would just be:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('_3hqu'); 
var i = 0;
while (i < el.length) {
  el[i].click();
  i++;
}
```

Comment: @SteliosM.: You don't need to set `objDiv.scrollTop` in the loop, there is nothing that is changed by the loop, and it doesn't matter where in the code you set the property as the browser won't actually do any scrolling until your code ends.

Comment: And how can i scroll down when it clicks the last item??? Because when i scroll down other items appear that were not there before.

Comment: @SteliosM.: If you want something to happen on a click then you need to bind a click event to the element. You don't need a loop to find the last element, just use `el[el.length - 1].onclick = function(){ };` and put the code for scrolling in the function.

Answer (score 1):

not quite sure what you are trying to do, but to convert it to the equivalent while loop

```
var i=0;
while(i<el.length) { 
  el[i].click(); 
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First there is something wrong in your if blocks: `el[1].length = 0` you are assigning, not value checking.

Change that to: `el[1].length == 0`

The same for the other line: `el[0].length = 0` to `el[0].length == 0`

Comment: i get  SyntaxError: Illegal break statement

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you want to use this ugly **while** instead of **for** but it is your code.
Main problem with this code is in condition:

```
length = 0
```

with this you assign into **length** attribute value 0. To compare you have to use:

```
length == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true)
{
    if ( el[0].length != 1 )
    {
        if ( el[1].length = 0 ) // should probably be a comparison (==), not an assignemnt (=)
        {
            el[1].click();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    else if ( el[0].length = 0 ) // should probably be a comparison (==), not an assignemnt (=). If so, will this condition every change during the loop, so that it will actually terminate at some time?
    {
        el[0].click();
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('_3hqu'); // This should probably be done before the loop, rather than in it. Otherwise, what will `el` be before this assignment?
}
```